# hg revert or update to browse commits and then change back to newest?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

If your just want to compile and run some code then go back without any changes what's standard practise?  (EDIT: assume the parent is at tip to begin with)

```
hg revert -C -r 0 --all

hg revert -C -r tip --all
```

### OR

```
hg update -C -r 0

hg update -C -r tip
```

I'm ok with deleting uncommitted stuff (-C) but is there any prefered way.
<strike>Also annoyingly tortoisehg doesn't seem to do the revert workflow with a click any ideas?</strike>
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.tortoisehg.user/2728

P.S I know update move's the parent and revert does not.

Comment: What do you want to do ? I really don't understand what "If your just want to compile and run some code". If you simply want to discard local changes, `hg up -C` will do the trick nicely.

Comment: I'm saying I just want to see what the program did back then by running it. I do not want to commit anything until I first change back to tip(as shown), discarding what I ran.

Comment: I should also add if you know a third command that does it better please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update is the better choice.  That way if you forget and make a code tweak you're in a position to commit it, possibly creating a new head, which is okay.

Comment: Hmm fair call.  If your absolutely bent on not creating a new head in your project (all linear) is there any other downsides?

Comment: A VCS history that looks like it was braided is the mark of a DVCS tool well used.  Linear histories were the sad result of inadequate pre-DVCS tools.  Merging in a DVCS should be a daily occurrence, not the to-be-avoided nightmare it was in CVS/svn.  That said you cal always use `hg rebase` later if you value aesthetics over accuracy.

Comment: Ok Mercurial backs this up here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_want_to_retrieve_an_old_version_of_my_project.2C_what_do_I_do.3F